# postMessage from local domain to remote domain

Tags: google-chrome, postmessage

With [tampermonkey](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/tampermonkey/dhdgffkkebhmkfjojejmpbldmpobfkfo?hl=en) I am running this Javascript inside an iframe in my page:

```
document.addEventListener("message", function(e){
  console.log('asd');
}, false);
```

This way I could receive messages from parent window. I am using jQuery Mobile and have this HTML:

```
<div data-role="page" data-url="/scraps/new?for=http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_hotels_in_Australia" tabindex="0" class="ui-page ui-body-c ui-page-active" style="min-height: 258px;">
    <p class="notice"></p>

    <p class="alert"></p>
    <iframe id="test" name="scrap" src="http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_hotels_in_Australia" width="100%"></iframe>
</div>
```

But when I do this in browser console:

```
var win = document.getElementById("test").contentWindow; // undefined

win
Unsafe JavaScript attempt to access frame with URL http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_hotels_in_Australia from frame with URL http://localhost:3001/scraps/new?for=http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_hotels_in_Australia. Domains, protocols and ports must match.
Unsafe JavaScript attempt to access frame with URL http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_hotels_in_Australia from frame with URL http://localhost:3001/scraps/new?for=http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_hotels_in_Australia. Domains, protocols and ports must match.
Unsafe JavaScript attempt to access frame with URL http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_hotels_in_Australia from frame with URL http://localhost:3001/scraps/new?for=http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_hotels_in_Australia. Domains, protocols and ports must match.
Unsafe JavaScript attempt to access frame with URL http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_hotels_in_Australia from frame with URL http://localhost:3001/scraps/new?for=http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_hotels_in_Australia. Domains, protocols and ports must match.
Window {}

win.postMessage('aaaa')
Error: SyntaxError: DOM Exception 12
```

Comment: Have you heard of the Same Origin Policy?

Comment: Can you tell me why it works here http://ejohn.org/blog/cross-window-messaging/? `One acting as the sender (on ejohn.org), one acting as the receiver (on dev.jquery.com).` Should I need inner iframe to set a Header.

Comment: The demo on the page you linked to is not operational. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy

Comment: @Mooseman the demo above on John Resig's site appears to work fine for me. postMessage() is a method that was created explicitly for the use-case of bypassing Same Origin Policy.

Comment: @juanpastas While postMessage() works cross-domain, it doesn't appear to work between local and remote contexts in my own testing, so you'll either need to run it between two local servers or two remote ones.

Comment: That's weird, what does it mean local and remote? local: 127.0.0.1 will communicate with which other? remote: ejohn.org and dev.jquery.com?